# In Python, how to sort a dataframe containing accents?

Tags: python, string, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I use sort_values to sort a dataframe. The dataframe contains UTF-8 characters with accents. Here is an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame ( [ ['i'],['e'],['a'],['é'] ] )
>>> df.sort_values(by=[0])
   0
2  a
1  e
0  i
3  é
```

As you can see, the "é" with an accent is at the end instead of being after the "e" without accent.

Note that the real dataframe has several columns !

Comment: I would recommend stripping diacritics for the sorting, then re-adding them.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Have you been introduced to `locale` yet?

Comment: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)

Comment: Could you be more specific about diacritics and locale ?

Answer (score 6):

This is one way. The simplest solution, as suggested by @JonClements:

```
df = df.iloc[df[0].str.normalize('NFKD').argsort()]
```

An alternative, long-winded solution, normalization code [courtesy of @EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926512/9209546):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['i'],['e'],['a'],['é']])

df = df.iloc[df[0].str.normalize('NFKD').argsort()]

# remove accents
df[1] = df[0].str.normalize('NFKD')\
             .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')\
             .str.decode('utf-8')

# sort by new column, then drop
df = df.sort_values(1, ascending=True)\
       .drop(1, axis=1)

print(df)

   0
2  a
1  e
3  é
0  i
```

---

Comment: In this case - might be that: `df.iloc[df[0].str.normalize('NFKD').argsort()]` is all that's needed...

Comment: Do we need the encoding into ASCII?  As soon as we do that, we no longer have all the és after all the es.

Comment: @DSM, That's a good point, but which *should* come first, `e` or `é`?

Comment: *As you can see, the "é" with an accent is at the end instead of being after the "e" without accent.* - seems to imply it's preferred that it's after the plain ASCII character... but why that should really *matter* at the end of the day instead of just being "with it" is another question...