# Remove accents from a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unidecoder

I have a dataframe that looks like:

| words |
| --- |
| Atlántica |
| Común |
| Guión |

and I want to remove all accents from each elemnt.

What I'm doing is:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode.unidecode(df['words'])
```

as a result I'm obtaining an error message that says:

```
'function' object has no atribute 'unidecode'
```

Can anyone help me?
Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove accents from values in columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926248/how-to-remove-accents-from-values-in-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing `unidecode` and then calling it again as an attribute. Try this:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode(df['words'])
```

Based on the error (`'Series' object hast no attribute 'encode'`) you're getting after trying this, my guess would be this should work:

```
df['words'] = df['words'].apply(unidecode)
```

Comment: When I do this I obtain a message that says: 'Series' object hast no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Can you please provide more clarity about the data in that case ?

Comment: @alelew Please check the edit if it works.