# How to replace accented characters in PySpark?

Tags: string, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, diacritics

I have a string column in a dataframe with values with accents, like

```
'México', 'Albânia', 'Japão'
```

How to replace letters with accents to get this:

```
'Mexico', 'Albania', 'Japao'
```

I tried many solutions available in Stack OverFlow, like this:

```py
def strip_accents(s):
   return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
                  if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

But disappointed returns

```
strip_accents('México')
>>> 'M?xico'
```

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `translate`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('1','Japão'),
    ('2','Irã'),
    ('3','São Paulo'),
    ('5','Canadá'),
    ('6','Tókio'),
    ('7','México'),
    ('8','Albânia')
    ],
    ["id", "Local"]
)

df.show(truncate = False)

+---+---------+
|id |Local    |
+---+---------+
|1  |Japão    |
|2  |Irã      |
|3  |São Paulo|
|5  |Canadá   |
|6  |Tókio    |
|7  |México   |
|8  |Albânia  |
+---+---------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df\
    .withColumn('Loc_norm', F.translate('Local',
                                       'ãäöüẞáäčďéěíĺľňóôŕšťúůýžÄÖÜẞÁÄČĎÉĚÍĹĽŇÓÔŔŠŤÚŮÝŽ',
                                       'aaousaacdeeillnoorstuuyzAOUSAACDEEILLNOORSTUUYZ'))\
    .show(truncate=False)

+---+---------+---------+
|id |Local    |Loc_norm |
+---+---------+---------+
|1  |Japão    |Japao    |
|2  |Irã      |Ira      |
|3  |São Paulo|Sao Paulo|
|5  |Canadá   |Canada   |
|6  |Tókio    |Tokio    |
|7  |México   |Mexico   |
|8  |Albânia  |Albânia  |
+---+---------+---------+
```

Comment: This work! But replace thhe letters e for a, example México to Maxico, lol.

But, I think my problem is in the config on aws cluster

Comment: Maybe the encoding of your file is not UTF-8

Comment: Why the Albânia continue with accent?

Comment: Seems that ```â``` is not on the list...

Comment: i like this one solution,

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, you can create a [**`pandas_udf`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) which is vectorized, so it's preferred to a regular `udf`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926248/how-to-remove-accents-from-values-in-columns#37926512) seems to be the best way to do it in pandas. So, we can use it to create a `pandas_udf` for PySpark application.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

@F.pandas_udf('string')
def strip_accents(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('utf-8')
```

Test:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('México',), ('Albânia',), ('Japão',)], ['country'])

df = df.withColumn('country2', strip_accents('country'))

df.show()
# +-------+--------+
# |country|country2|
# +-------+--------+
# | México|  Mexico|
# |Albânia| Albania|
# |  Japão|   Japao|
# +-------+--------+
```