# pandas: str.replace fails on Spanish characters

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a simple script that converts values from one type to another using `str.replace`. It works fine for values using standard English characters but it seems confused by Spanish characters like
ñ.

Example:

```
df['Best time to call?'] = df['Best time to call?']\
    .str.replace('Afternoons / La tarde','afternoon')\
    .str.replace('Evenings / La noche','evening')\
    .str.replace('Do Not Call / No llamar','')\
    .str.replace('Morning / La mañana','morning')
```

The converted values are output to a CSV through pandas. When I open the CSV in Excel, `'Morning / La mañana'` has been converted to `'Morning / La maï¿½ana'` even though all the other ones worked.

***EDIT***

The older question you all have suggested was specific to python 2 and I am using python 3.

I have found that preemptively replacing the mojibake solves the issue.

```
df['Best time to call?'] = df['Best time to call?'].str.replace('�', 'n')
```

followed by:

```
df['Best time to call?'] = df['Best time to call?'.str.replace('Morning / La manana','morning')
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it will do for now.

Comment: Have you checked out the response here? I think it should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839465/python-pandas-replace-special-character

Comment: Your issue might be fixed with the proper UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Replace Special Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839465/python-pandas-replace-special-character)

Comment: This is not a failure. You have written the file out as UTF-8 but Excel thinks the encoding is Windows-1252. This has a name: *mojibake*, a Japanese name for a problem that first appeared with East Asian scripts but has now become a worldwide plague. What to do depends on what you want. If you want it to look right in Excel, open the file in your program with `encoding="cp1252"`. If you are just using Excel to inspect the file, use something else, such as Notepad++ (free), to view it.

Comment: I always make a point to check for older answers before posting a question but somehow missed this one. Thanks. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Excel problem, not a Pandas problem.

Excel is interpreting your UTF-8 encoded CSV file as ISO-8859-1, leading to the [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) you're seeing.

Either

- use Excel's Open dialog -> Open Text File -> set the encoding to UTF-8
- save your file as e.g. XLS, which is always opened with a correct encoding by Excel
- save the CSV file as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 (not recommended; you can't represent all characters in ISO-8859-1, and many other software expects UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, but I don't it's Excel. The code is supposed to convert 'Morning / La mañana' to 'morning,' so the character shouldn't even be there for Excel to misinterpret.